# Xcode 7 code coverage problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, code-coverage

Ok, so I've got an app that was absolutely fine with Xcode 6.4.

But ever since upgrading to Xcode 7 I'm not able to generate GCDA files to feed into XcodeCoverage for my coverage report. To generate the files I need to set INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW to YES. But setting it to YES causes my test run to fail. Lots of "cannot merge previous GCDA file: corrupt arc tag" entries in the console, and it then crashes in main.m showing BAD_ACCESS on the line calling UIApplicationMain.

I would really rather not use the new LLVM coverage report as it's not detailed enough.

Anyone have any ideas for this?